# Is it possible to implement Panel controls in ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: asp.net, panel

I have been tasked to create a web interface for a POS terminal. I was thinking of using Javascript to display button values on a panel. But my boss insists I use Panel Controls. Is this applicable in ASP.net MVC5, and how do I implement this?

Comment: These controls are only for WebForms. However you can use third party controls: https://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/ and few other commercial products.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those options out